# Regular language? Union of the dictionary and an non-regular language

Tags: regular-languages

I'm attempting to figure out if a union of two languages is regular.

$$
L_1 = \{all\ the\ words\ in\ the\ Oxford\ dictionary\} \\
L_2 = \{w : w\ has\ twice\ as\ many\ a's\ as\ b's\}
$$

$L_2$ is well established to be a non-regular language. However, I am not sure if $L_1$ would be considered a regular language. The language should be finite (albeit large), which suggests it is regular, but I'm not certain.

If $L_1$ is regular, then I would consider the union $L_1 \cup L_2 $ would also be regular, as by the same argument, the language would be finite.

What does everyone think?

Comment: ***L1*** **union** ***L2*** is not regular as the previous answer suggests but ***L1*** **intersection** ***L2*** is definitely regular. As their intersection will contain only the common elements of both the sets, which will finite and also regular.

Comment: You seem to have serious issues with the definition of union of languages. The union of a finite and an infinite set is always infinite. Unless you mean ***intersection***, but that is a very different question.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to see that $L_1 \cup L_2$ is not regular is through closure properties of the regular languages.

**Theorem.** If $L_1$ is finite and $L_2$ is not regular, then $L_1 \cup L_2$ is not regular.

**Proof.** Since $L_1 \setminus L_2$ is finite, it is regular.
Suppose $L = L_1 \cup L_2$ were regular. Then $L \setminus (L_1 \setminus L_2) = L_2$ would also be regular, contrary to assumption. $\qquad\square$

Answer (score 1):

$L_1$ is indeed finite. But the union $L_1\cup L_2$ contains everything that is in $L_1$ and also everything that is in $L_2$.  Thus, the union of a finite set and an infinite set is infinite.

In this case, $L_1\cup L_2$ is not regular: you can prove this using the pumping lemma, Myhill–Nerode or any other technique you might have been taught.

Comment: More generally, I think the union of any irregular/non-context-free/non-context-sensitive language and a finite language is irregular/non-context-free/non-context-sensitive.